# What are the beliefs and practices of Evangelicals regarding ecumenism?

Tags: faith, evangelicalism, ecumenism, denomination

I want to know what Evangelical Christians (ECs) believe regarding ecumenism and how they practice it.

A very practical example is when a person converts interdenominationally. How do ECs make the convert feel like his/her conversion to EC does not imply that his/her entire faith journey up to that point was invalid since they used to believe different to what they now do?

Another practical example is where an EC wishes to not make Christians from other denominations feel like they are belittling their faith because they, as an EC, hold to their views while fellowshipping with them.

Comment: "Ecumenism" means cooperation between Christian groups. You seem to be asking about interdenominational conversions.

Comment: Should I edit that to ecumenical then? Would that be better wording? I am not a theologian so I would definitely be using the wrong term...

Comment: "Ecumenical" is just the adjective form of "Ecumenism".

Comment: Okay, I see that my use of the term is incorrect. I am looking for a term that describes the interaction between churches with differing beliefs.

Comment: You may have the right word then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [ecumenism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecumenism), most Evangelical Christians hold that there are certain truths which are necessary to apprehend by faith in order to actually be saved.  Different EC denominations may have a slightly different list of these truths but for the most part the list centers around the following (taken from an [EC website](https://www.gotquestions.org/essentials-Christian-faith.html)):

1. The deity of Christ
2. Salvation by grace
3. Salvation through faith in Jesus Christ alone
4. The resurrection of Jesus Christ
5. The Gospel as outlined in [1 Corinthians 15:1-4](https://biblia.com/bible/esv/1-corinthians/15/1-4)
6. Monotheism
7. The Holy Trinity

There are other things which are indoctrinated in differing EC denominations that are considered "secondary truths" and, while each denomination holds that their particular secondary truths are, in fact, truth they will not claim that differing beliefs in this category disqualify one from salvation.  This list includes things like beliefs regarding [continuationism](https://www.gotquestions.org/continuationism.html), the nature and timing of the [Rapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapture), and [Sabbath worship](https://christiananswers.net/q-eden/rhodes-sabbath.html) to name a scant few.

EC, in theory, will regard those who hold to category 1 (necessary truths) items as fellow Christians regardless of the category 2 (secondary truths) differences.  Joint worship may be uncomfortable or difficult if the category 2 differences are striking, such as those who prefer hymns attending services with contemporary music, but fellowship and joint gospel ministry should be possible.

> Let us therefore, as many as be perfect, be thus minded: and if in any thing ye be otherwise minded, God shall reveal even this unto you. - Philippians 3:15

EC, in theory, will regard as unbelievers those who do not hold to category 1 items.  This makes Christian fellowship, joint worship and joint gospel ministry impossible.

> I marvel that ye are so soon removed from him that called you into the grace of Christ unto another gospel: Which is not another; but there be some that trouble you, and would pervert the gospel of Christ. But though we, or an angel from heaven, preach any other gospel unto you than that which we have preached unto you, let him be accursed. - Galatians 1:6-8

Hatred and ill will, however, should have no place in the EC heart regarding these but rather intercession in prayer and great patience in presenting the truth with faith that the Lord God knows those who are his:

> I exhort therefore, that, first of all, supplications, prayers, intercessions, and giving of thanks, be made for all men; For kings, and for all that are in authority; that we may lead a quiet and peaceable life in all godliness and honesty. For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour - 1 Timothy 2:1-3

> Preach the word; be instant in season, out of season; reprove, rebuke, exhort with all longsuffering and doctrine. For the time will come when they will not endure sound doctrine; but after their own lusts shall they heap to themselves teachers, having itching ears; And they shall turn away their ears from the truth, and shall be turned unto fables. But watch thou in all things, endure afflictions, do the work of an evangelist, make full proof of thy ministry. - 2 Timothy 4:2-5

There are instances where a denomination requires belief in certain teachings which fall outside of category 1.  Belief in these can obscure the simple truths of the Gospel and, while such belief may not negate salvation it does not necessarily lead to salvation and EC would regard such belief as highly dangerous.  An example of this are the [4 Marion Dogmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Mariology) which the Roman Catholic Church requires its members to believe and espouse.  Because of situations such as this ecumenism should never be sought as an end unto itself.  The foundational truths of the Gospel of Jesus Christ can move forward within the context of ecumenism just as wheat grows in amongst the tares but should never be sacrificed for the sake of ecumenism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. This gives me better perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The size of most Evangelical denominations is somewhere between "small" and "extremely small". My denomination has about 10,000-20,000. Moreover most denominations are simply loose associations of independent congregations. The US Southern Baptists, for example, don't hold any authority over their congregations. Congregations can do whatever they want, can set their own statements of faith, can leave at any time, and the worst sanction that the denomination has is to eject the congregation (an action that will have very little consequence on the members of the congregation).

The result of this is that in a medium sized town where there may be twenty or thirty evangelical congregations, all belonging to different denominations. Each independent congregation is responsible for deciding to admit its own members. Anyone changing churches is very likely to be coming from a different denomination, and even if they came from the same denomination that congregation they came from might not have the same beliefs the new one does. Changing churches is also common within Evangelicalism, and is usually nothing to do with theology -it's more likely to be about the quality of youth programs, the music style, the style of teaching, or some minor disagreement with the church.

All of which is to say that Evangelicals "convert" a lot, in the sense of changing denomination. Because of this it's usually no big deal. You simply start showing up at a new church, you are welcomed, get to know people, maybe volunteer to help out. At some point you will decide to formally transfer your membership, and this just involves signing a piece of paper. You will probably have to sign that you agree with your new church's statement of faith, but this is pretty much never an issue. A lot of people couldn't even tell you the doctrinal differences between their previous church and the new one. There is absolutely no worry that a previous faith journey is "invalid".

The only exception to this is if you join a denomination that requires believer baptism, and you were baptised as an infant. In those cases a re-baptism is usually required, and that can be a big hurdle for many people. But most such denominations don't require baptism to be an active participant. You can often take part in a church fully for many years without being baptised.

I am excluding "mainstream" Protestants here, like Lutherans or Anglicans, but even than a "conversion" from another protestant denomination isn't a big deal